# Add a string at the end of a string for a particular string inside a String

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have a big string that contains several strings like the following:

`http://website.com/image.jpg` and I want to add `?w=100` to each of them.

So far I thought about creating a regular expression where every time I would encounter that string, it would replace it by the same string with the `?w=100` added to it.

Here is an extension of `String` to replace the string:

```
public func stringByReplacingMatches(matchRegEx: String, withMatch: String) -> String {
    do {
        let regEx = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: matchRegEx, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions())
        return regEx.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count), withTemplate: withMatch)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error in the regular expression: \"\(matchRegEx)\"")
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
myString.stringByReplacingMatches("https:\\/\\/website\\.com\\/[\\w\\D]*.jpg", withMatch: "https:\\/\\/website\\.com\\/[\\w\\D]*.jpg?w=100"))
```

Problem, this is what I get after replacing the string:

```
https://website.com/[wD]*.jpg?w=100
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about [capture groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/):

```
myString.stringByReplacingMatches("(https:\\/\\/website\\.com\\/[\\w\\D]*.jpg)", withMatch: "$1?w=100")
```

---

Oh and don't forget to save the return value

```
let fixedString = myString.stringByReplacingMatches("(https:\\/\\/website\\.com\\/[\\w\\D]*.jpg)", withMatch: "$1?w=100")
```

`myString` will not change, but `fixedString` will have all the updates.

---

**UPDATE**

`[\\w\\D]*` matches any character. You need to craft a more specific regular expression.

For the input `"https://website.com/x.jpg" "https://website.com/x.jpg"`, the regex `\w` works.

```
var myString = "\"https://website.com/x.jpg\" \"https://website.com/x.jpg\""
myString = myString.stringByReplacingMatches("(https:\\/\\/website\\.com\\/\\w*.jpg)", withMatch: "$1?w=100")
```

But this will not work for every possible URL.

Comment: Why do you need a capture group if you can use `$0` to insert the matched string?

Comment: @paulvs I prefer to be explicit. `$0` works, but is less flexible.

Comment: It works thanks but only for the last occurrence. How can I make it work for all the occurrences in my big string? I guess the regex is fine, it's probably the function.

Comment: @Nico `\w` matches any word, `\D` matches any non-digit. Between the two, it matches every character. You need a better regular expression.

Comment: Yes I realised it afterwards... I ended up using this regex: [\\w-$+()*!']*. Might need to get a better one though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should call it as

```
myString.stringByReplacingMatches("https:\\/\\/website\\.com\\/[\\w\\D]*.jpg", withMatch: "$0?w=100"))
```

The template can use `$0` to show the matching string. You should not repeat the matching regular expression there.

Comment: It works thanks but only for the last occurrence. How can I make it work for all the occurrences in my big string? I guess the regex is fine, it's probably the function.

Comment: Your matchign expression is too broad.  Try `myString.stringByReplacingMatches("http:\\/\\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-zA-Z0-9]*", withMatch: "$0?w=100"))` That may work from some URLs, but I would look for a better regular expression to detect all different types of URLs. For your original question, the template change is the correct solution.  The correct matching of URLs in a larger string is a different question altogether.

Comment: Yes I realised it afterwards... I ended up using this regex: [\\w-$+()*!']*. Might need to get a better one though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "http:\\/\\/[a-z]*.[a-z]*\\/[a-z]*.[a-z]*", options: .CaseInsensitive)
    var newString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(a, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, a.characters.count), withTemplate: "$0?w=100")
    print(newString)
}
```